# Windows 10: unable to start mysql service from wamp64 - auth_socket

Tags: mysql, wamp, wampserver

I am unable to start mysql service from wamp64. When I try to manually start mysql from the installed directory using `mysql -u root`, I get the following message: 
`ERROR 1524 <HY000>: Plugin 'auth_socket' is not loaded`.

Any idea on how to fix it? These are the contents in the log:

```
[Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
[Warning] Insecure configuration for --secure-file-priv: Current value does not restrict location of generated files. Consider setting it to a valid, non-empty path.
[Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.14) starting as process 9352 ...
[Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
[Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
[Note] InnoDB: _mm_lfence() and _mm_sfence() are used for memory barrier
[Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
[Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
[Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
[Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
[Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
[Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
[Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 5837170719
[Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 5837170728
[Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 5837170728
[Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
[Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
[Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
[Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
[Note] InnoDB: Setting file '.\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
[Note] InnoDB: File '.\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
[Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
[Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
[Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
[Note] InnoDB: 5.7.14 started; log sequence number 5837170728
[Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from D:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.14\data\ib_buffer_pool
[Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
[ERROR] Can't open shared library 'D:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.14\lib\plugin\auth_socket.so' (errno: 126 The specified module could not be found.)
[Warning] Couldn't load plugin named 'auth_socket' with soname 'auth_socket.so'.
[ERROR] InnoDB: Column table_name in table `mysql`.`innodb_table_stats` is VARCHAR(597) NOT NULL but should be VARCHAR(192) NOT NULL (length mismatch).
[ERROR] InnoDB: Fetch of persistent statistics requested for table `mysql`.`gtid_executed` but the required system tables mysql.innodb_table_stats and mysql.innodb_index_stats are not present or have unexpected structure. Using transient stats instead.
[Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 190105  1:20:08
[Warning] Failed to set up SSL because of the following SSL library error: SSL context is not usable without certificate and private key
[Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
[Note] IPv6 is available.
[Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
[Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
[Warning] The plugin 'auth_socket' used to authenticate user 'root'@'localhost' is not loaded. Nobody can currently login using this account.
[Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
[Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.14'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)`
```

Comment: I am assuming you have mad some changes to the default MySQL configuration. Can you tell us what you did please.

Comment: I have MySQL workbench 8 installed as well. When I close the MySQL workbench, and restart mysql service with WAMP it does start. But when I enter password in phpmyadmin page, it says: `mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1524): Plugin 'auth_socket' is not loaded`

Comment: My guess is that you installed MySQL Workbench with its own MySQL Server. So now you have 2 MySQL server instances on your system. Which ever one started first grabs port 3306 and stop s the other starting. I would suggest removing the MySQL server instance that came with MySQL Workbench, after backing up any databases. Workbench can then be used to access the MySQL that comes with WAMPServer

Comment: But the mysql server with WAMP does start now after closing the other server.